# Update a variable after executing a future function

Tags: flutter

I have a function called `ff` which takes 2 images, and returns an `outputimage` , I"d like to update the original image, when the user taps on any of the style images, and display the `outputimage` instead of the original one . I know I should use `setstate` somehow, but I'm confused on how and where

code :

```
Future ff(String styleImagePath, String originalImagePath) async {
  ImageTransferFacade showtime = ImageTransferFacade();

  var original_image = showtime.loadoriginalImage(originalImagePath);

  var style_image = showtime.loadStyleImage(styleImagePath);

  var output_image = showtime.transfer(await original_image, await style_image);
  return output_image;
}

class second extends StatefulWidget {
  const second({
    Key? key,
    required this.image,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final XFile image;

  @override
  State<second> createState() => _secondState();
}

class _secondState extends State<second> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Card(
                  child: Image.file(File(widget.image
                      .path))))), // this is the original image which i'd like to replace once user taps on the style image
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CarouselSlider.builder(
          itemCount: imageList.length,
          options: CarouselOptions(
            autoPlay: true,
            aspectRatio: 2.0,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index, realIdx) {
            return Container(
                child: Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => ff(imageList[index], widget.image.path),
                  child: Image.network(imageList[index],
                      fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
            ));
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: const FloatingActionButton(onPressed: null),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future ff(String styleImagePath, String originalImagePath) async {
  ImageTransferFacade showtime = ImageTransferFacade();

  var original_image = showtime.loadoriginalImage(originalImagePath);

  var style_image = showtime.loadStyleImage(styleImagePath);

  var output_image = showtime.transfer(await original_image, await style_image);
  return output_image;
}


class second extends StatefulWidget {
  const second({
    Key? key,
    required this.image,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final XFile image;

  @override
  State<second> createState() => _secondState();
}

class _secondState extends State<second> {

  late XFile _image;

  initState(){
    _image = widget.image;
    super.initState();
  }

 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Card(
                  child: Image.file(File(image
                      .path))))), // this is the original image which i'd like to replace once user taps on the style image
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CarouselSlider.builder(
          itemCount: imageList.length,
          options: CarouselOptions(
            autoPlay: true,
            aspectRatio: 2.0,
            enlargeCenterPage: true,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index, realIdx) {
            return Container(
                child: Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
  ff(imageList[index], widget.image.path).then((value){
   setState((){
     _image = value;
   });
  });
},                  child: Image.network(imageList[index],
                      fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
            ));
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: const FloatingActionButton(onPressed: null),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but I get this error: `The method 'ff' isn't defined for the type '_secondState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ff'.` plus a couple from closing formats and I don't know why , but I need to add widget.image instead of just image!

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it @koko99

Comment: Although it throws an error: unable to load asset! , but I think it's a different issue . Thanks